# Trying to access node content with PHP

Tags: 7, nodes

I have the following code to load a different node into my homepage:

```
<?php $node = node_load(2); ?>
<div class="modal hide fade" id="security">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
      <h3><?php echo $node->title; ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <?php render( $node->content ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The title displays, but the content doesn't. I get the error `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$content in include()`

Based on what I read [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) I feel this should work. What do I need to do to make the node content display? (it's just a basic page w/ title and body)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The node's content isn't built when you load the node, you need to invoke it manually with [`node_build_content()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_build_content/7):

```
$node = node_load(2);
node_build_content($node, $view_mode);

// You now have access to $node->content
```

Comment: What Clive said.

Comment: render( $node_content ) isn't doing anything. I guess I will have to find which section or the array I need

Comment: @Damon It should be `print render($node->content)`, the node is an object once it's loaded

Comment: ah I was assuming the echo/print was included with the render. beautiful!